# Implementing basic server paging on tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I'm having troubles implementing server side paging with tablesorter.

I read json data from a server, but there are too many records to get the entire data set all at once, so I need to reduce loading time with server side paging.

My first implementation (with client side paging) reads json data from the server and builds the html table with all the data inside, then pager initialization does the rest. It is fundamental to say that json data is read by a custom function that builds the table recursively with all the options I need and data inside: I have 20+ fileds to show and I need to add css classes, handlers and decorations depending on some parameters I get from the context, so I cannot just write a static table and let tablesorter to handle it.

I guess mine is a common scenario, but I wonder how to do the same thing with server side paging. Of course I have to get rid of the custom function that is currently managing the entire data set and writes the actual table. How can I apply the same concept (say a transformation function) to every request made by the pager plugin in server side paging mode? 
From the docs I guess this role is demanded to ajaxProcessing binded function, but I'm not able to make it work and I don't really know how to achieve the same result I got with my previous implementation.

Just to clarify a little more what I need, I paste the function I mentioned, the one that builds table and bind data coming from json. Again, this function is called before tablesorter initialization, and its job is to write data and setup attributes, classes and bindings to achieve whatever my application is supposed to do:

```
// This function creates a standard table with column/rows
// Parameter Information
// objArray = Anytype of object array, like JSON results
// tableId = Id of the container of the table (not a table element itself!)
// dateColumns = String array containing names of date fields (for formatting parser) - case insensitive
// orderedFields = String array containing field names ordered as requested - case sensitive
// readOnly = boolean, defines whether a particular field has to be shown in readonly o read/write mode
function CreateTableOrderedView(objArray, tableId, dateColumns, orderedFields, readOnly) {
    // If the returned data is an object do nothing, else try to parse
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

    var str = '<table id="' + tableId + '" class="tablesorter tablesorter-blue">';

    // table head
    str += '<thead><tr class="tablesorter-headerRow" role="row">';
    for (var index = 0; index < orderedFields.length; index++) {
        str += ($.inArray(orderedFields[index].toUpperCase(), dateColumns) == -1 ? '<th scope="col" class="' + orderedFields[index].toUpperCase() + '">' + orderedFields[index] + '</th>' : '<th scope="col" class="' + orderedFields[index].toUpperCase() + ' sorter-ddmmyy">' + orderedFields[index] + '</th>');
    }
    str += '</tr></thead>';

    // table body
    str += '<tbody>';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        str += '<tr>';
        for (var column = 0; column < orderedFields.length; column++) {
            //If the current field is the one that can be edited (this piece of information has to be added to the function parameters list) and it's not in readonly mode, add some handlers to correctly handle contentEditable selections and empty data
            if (orderedFields[column].toUpperCase() != 'ACTIVATIONDATE' || readOnly)
                str += '<td class="' + orderedFields[column].toUpperCase() + '"><div>' + (eval('array[i].' + orderedFields[column]) != null ? eval('array[i].' + orderedFields[column]) : '') + '</div></td>';
            else
                str += '<td class="' + orderedFields[column].toUpperCase() + '"><div ' + (eval('array[i].' + orderedFields[column]) != null ? '' : 'class="emptyPlaceholder"') + 'onmouseup="javascript:SelectActivationDateText(this);" onblur="javascript:RestoreCellStyle(this);">' + (eval('array[i].' + orderedFields[column]) != null ? eval('array[i].' + orderedFields[column]) : emptyTextString) + '</div></td>';
        }
        str += '</tr>';
    }
    str += '</tbody>';
    str += '</table>';

    return str;
}
```

I'd like to obtain a similar result applying these rules for every page requested, so that every time I can setup visible rows to behave like they do in the client side paging implementation, but I have troubles understanding how exactly I should do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found by myself what I've been looking for.

Basicly to achieve what I was doing with the quoted function in a server side paging scenario, you have to implement an handler to bind to ajaxProcessing property in tablesorterPager settings. 
In this function you can bind data to the table cells, but you also have the option to control the table markup itself and customize it as you need.

An example that implements that function to obtain a very similar result I got with the one I quoted in my previous post can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999790/cannot-use-contenteditable-widget-on-server-side-paged-tablesorter).